# Как записать значение select в переменную? Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Не могу записать результат `select` в переменную.

Делаю так:

```
Id_new = (select max(id)+1 from workes.prod);
```

В интернете нашла такой вариант:

```
select max(id)+1 into Id_new from workes.prod
```

но как я понимаю, это вариант для записи результата в столбец таблицы, а у меня 
`Id_new` просто переменная,
`workes` - база данных, `prod` - таблица.

В *Microsoft SQL* такой вариант работал, а в *PostgreSQL* нет :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я так понимаю вы пишете внутри хранимой процедуры, в ней такой вариант

```sql
select 'something' into myVar;
```

будет записывать значение именно в переменную а не в таблицу

пример функции

```sql
create or replace function getNextId(
) returns bigint
as $$
declare
  Id_new bigint;
begin
  select max(id) + 1 into Id_new from my_table;
  return Id_new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

но вообще если вам нужно как то получать последовательные значения то лучше воспользоваться sequence:

```sql
create sequence db.sequence_custom_name;
create table db.my_table(id bigint);
insert into db.my_table values(nextval('db.sequence_custom_name'));
```